# About the proof of Milnor-Novikov theorem about multiplicative generators of (complex) bordism ring

Tags: characteristic-classes, cobordism

I am trying to understand part of Milnor-Novikov theorem about multiplicative generators of $MU_* \cong \mathbb Z[x_1, x_2, \dots]$ using S.Kochman’s “Bordsim, Stable Homotopy and Adams Spectral Sequences”.

Namely, define
\begin{equation}
\gamma_n =
\begin{cases}
p\quad&\text{if $n = p^t -1$ for some prime $p$ and positive integer $t$};
\\
1\quad&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

> **Theorem. (Proposition 4.3.16 in the book)**
>   Element $x_n \in MU_*$ is a polynomial generator iff
>   \begin{equation}
> h(x_n) = \pm\gamma_n A_n + \mathrm{decomposable}\in H_*(MU; \mathbb Z).
> \end{equation}

I have understood the case $n \neq p^t-1$.
Can anybody explain to me what happens next?
Why does $h(x_{p^t-1})$ divisible by $p$ and not divisible by and other prime $p’$?

It seems that this is because of bidegree of $h(x_{p^t-1})$ in ASS, but I cannot understand why.

May be you can suggest me any readable source (different from Stong’s or Ravenel’s books) to find the proof?